# Как вызвать функцию в Python из C++?

Tags: c++, python

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void hello() {
    cout << "Hello!" << endl;
}
```

Как из Python вызвать это функцию?

Comment: Что-то подобное: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/using_custom_dll

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python

Comment: @gil9red, Не очень понял, можно другой пример?

Comment: @hoojpop, создается dll из сишного кода и вызываются ее функции в питоничьем кода. Подробнее -- это уже ответ оформлять, а мне не охото это делать :)

Comment: ctypes Вам в руки но он больше под Си с плюсиками там есть костыли)

Comment: Возможно вам подойдёт вариант компиляции программы на С++ в исполняемый файл и запуска его из python-скрипта отдельным процессом.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, как это можно сделать?

Comment: boost::python вам в помощь

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Очень понятно (нет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно выполнить какой-то код на С++, можно написать на С++ отдельную программу, скомпилировать её и вызвать из python-скрипта как отдельный процесс. При этом передавать аргументы в неё можно можно через argv или через файлы. Возвращать значения можно через stdout или через файлы.

Пример.

```
#include <iostream>

void hello(std::string name) {
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    hello(argv[1]);
}
```

Компилируем программу в `ConsoleApplication.exe`. В python запускаем её, передавая один аргумент, и получаем вывод этой программы в stdout.

```
p = subprocess.run(["./ConsoleApplication.exe", 'Bob'], capture_output=True)
output = str(p.stdout, 'utf8')
print(output)  # Hello, Bob
```